# Substituting garlic powder for garlic salt?

Tags: substitutions, salt, garlic

I love using garlic powder but I also see recipes call for garlic salt. I thought that you could just add garlic powder instead of garlic salt (which of course is sold separately!) and then just add some actual salt if necessary. What is the difference in doing this as opposed to using store-bought garlic salt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Taste-wise there will be little to not difference in the result. Just be careful to use the proper ratio of garlic to salt (generally 3-to-1 salt to garlic powder).

Comment: I use sea salt with garlic powder instead

Answer (score 5):

Garlic salt is 3 parts salt and 1 part garlic, plus an anti-caking agent. That means that 1 tsp of garlic salt contains 1/4 tsp of garlic powder, or a 4 to 1 substitution ratio.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garlic_salt

Comment: That equates to 3 to 1.

Comment: 1 part + 3 parts = 4 parts.
1 part out of 4 parts = 1/4.

Comment: Right. And that's 3 to 1. Not 4 to 1 as your answer says.

Comment: You are confusing substitution ratio and part ratio. There is 1/4 tsp garlic powder in 1 tsp garlic salt. So to substitute garlic powder in a recipe that calls for 1 tsp, we must add 4 tsp of garlic salt to get the required amount of garlic powder (and deal with the 3 teaspoons of added salt).

Comment: Vice versa, to substitute 1 tsp garlic salt, we would use 1/4 tsp garlic powder (and add 3/4 tsp regular salt).

Comment: I'd never heard the term substitution ratio, so my brain just ignored the word substitution. It makes sense now, but is still confusing.

Comment: Heh, your brain substituted the word substitution. :-)

Answer (score 3):

My family watches our salt intake so we usually use garlic powder in place of garlic salt and just add a tiny bit of salt to recipes.  It works perfectly for us.

Comment: Plus garlic salt is a remarkably Expensive way to purchase table salt.

Answer (score 2):

The quality , type  and freshness of the garlic powder will dictate how much to use.  Hardneck garlic powder is so flavorful, that you would mix it 5 parts salt to one part garlic powder.  Softneck garlic powder is mixed 3 to 1.   Store bought garlic powder is from the softneck variety and usually shipped in large vats from China.  The older the powder is, the weaker the flavor.  For best results,  buy dehydrated hardneck garlic and grind (I use an inexpensive coffee grinder) in small batches prior to using.