# garlic powder and onion powder substitutes

Tags: salt

recipe calls for 3/4 teaspoon garlic powder all I have is garlic salt also 1/2 teaspoon of onion powder and all I have is onion salt how much do I substitute for each

Comment: What are you making? Do you have actual garlic or onions? That would be a much preferable substitute than salts.

Comment: Does the recipe also have salt that you can swap out for garlic and onion salt? Garlic/onion salt is 3 parts salt to 1 part garlic/onion powder by volume. (so garlic or onion salt is a scam as they generally are almost as expensive as the powders)

Comment: @Catija onion/garlic powders do taste and behave differently than fresh garlic/onions (you certainly cannot put fresh ones into eg a seasoning mixture)... but they are not exactly that potent, so you can likely omit the normal salt and use the flavored salts up to the point where you reach salt balance. If it is a seasoning mixture (sounds like blackening spice....) that you want to store, salt might even be advantageous for preservation.

Comment: @Jolenealaska any reason (eg published industry standard) to assume that is not brand dependent or very regional?

Comment: @rackandboneman That ratio is all over the net, including here on SA: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/580/substituting-garlic-powder-for-garlic-salt/2731#2731

Comment: @rackandboneman That's why it would really be helpful to know what Crickett is making, as Catija first asked.

Answer (score 2):

A good substitute will be Asafoetida . It smells like blended onion and garlic . Taste wise , its a great substitute of onion and garlic .

Answer (score 0):

Try using celery salt, because unlike garlic or onion powder, it really brings out a nice flavor for meats whether it is a roast, or a grilled meat, it has a nice salty and celery twist.

I recommend using it on hot dogs, steak, and pork, with some vegetables such as carrots, leeks, onions, mushrooms, and potatoes.

Happy Cooking!

Comment: It may have a nice flavor, but it's no substitute for garlic or onion. You're also adding lots of extra salt, and the OP already has onion salt.